# Better Bone Selection in Weight Painting?

Tags: armature, interface, weight-painting

Of all the problems with weight painting, there is one that is more annoying: When selecting bones with Ctrl+LMB to test their movement, every time you click on a bone, the selection always adds bones and moving the active bone will always move every selected bone.

You have to Ctrl+LMB double click on every selected bone to deselect them, you have to keep doing this, if you want to test the weighting you just did.

My question is, is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALT+A to unselect everything, first.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: if this solved it for you, you may vote up the answer. Thanks

Comment: I can only upvote above 15 rep